# Uncaught TypeError: this.remove is not a function at <anonymous>:12:14

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am getting below error while running my reactjs application, not able to find out whether it is in my code or issue with some library or chrome extensions.

The error is in file:
 **chrome-extension://ojplmecpdpgccookcobabopnaifgidhf/utility_all2.js**

Can someone help me in understanding this ?

[image]

Comment: `this.remove()` is included in the injected code by mistake, apparently. Remove it.

Comment: @wOxxOm I am getting this error only in chrome, tested on Safari and Firefox.
It is coming when application is loaded, also my application is huge and the above file utility_all2.js where this error occurred is not part of my project.

Comment: Still, `this.remove()` is invalid in that place so find out what's adding it and remove it.

Comment: But I dont think it will affect your website in any way. We will get this fixed though :)

Comment: @PrashantSingh Thanks, yes it is not impacting my website but was curious about the error getting logged every time I loaded the site. :)

Answer (score 13):

Try to `disabled` one by one `google chrome extension` and refresh page.

Go to `chrome://extensions/`

In my case "`Buyhatke`" extension create issue. I disabled this extension and that error is gone.

Look like this extension is added some scripts, that is creating issue.

**Note:** I just added this answer, because it may help someone.

Comment: Thanks,  I too had "Buyhatke" extension added in chrome and it is actually an issue with this extension it seems. Disabling the extension, fixed the issue.

Comment: BuyHatke is the culprit in most of the cases. Came here to post the same answer.